# Azure Devops Microsoft-hosted Ubuntu agent integration tests fail to call Docker Rest Api

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, docker-daemon, azure-devops-hosted-agent

We have a problem with Azure pipeline.
Inside pipeline we are running integration tests, those tests interacts with Docker Rest API to run specific containers (we are using Docker.DotNet for that). Everything works on on-premise hosted build agent, but doesn't on Microsoft-hosted (Ubuntu based). All calls to Docker REST API ends with timeout exception.
Does Docker engine in Microsoft-hosted Ubuntu build agent contains Docker REST API?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?